# .DLL C++ function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, pinvoke

I'm using mpusbapi.dll in WPF project using C#. 
In C++ the function prototype is:

```
DWORD MPUSBWrite(HANDLE handle,         
             PVOID pData,           
             DWORD dwLen,           
             PDWORD pLength,        
             DWORD dwMilliseconds);
```

And my p/invoke in C# is:

```
[DllImport("mpusbapi.dll")]
private static extern DWORD _MPUSBWrite(void* handle, void* pData, DWORD dwLen, DWORD* pLength, DWORD dwMilliseconds);
```

So, because I dont make all my project unsafe, I want to buid this next method to send data:

```
unsafe private void SendPacket(byte* SendData, UInt32 SendLength)
{
     uint SendDelay = 10;
     UInt32 SentDataLength;

     openPipes();
     MPUSBWrite(myOutPipe, &SendData, SendLength, &SentDataLength, SendDelay);
     closePipes();
}
```

But Visual Studios show me an error with the variable type of the parameters. "Cannot convert from 'byte**' to 'system.IntPtr'" and "Cannot convert from 'uint*' to 'system.IntPtr'".
I am new using C # and now the pointers have me stuck. How should I translate the c++ parameter to C#? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I didn't notice that I've changed the Pinvoke to:

```
[DllImport("mpusbapi.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern UInt32 _MPUSBWrite(IntPtr handle,IntPtr pData, UInt32 dwLen,IntPtr pLength, UInt32 dwMilliseconds);
```

**ADD:**
Removing the & in the method call did not fix the last errors and added this one "Use of unassigned local variable 'SendDataLenght'".

Comment: Just try removing the `&` on your method call, like `_MPUSBWrite(myOutPipe, SendData, SendLength, SentDataLength, SendDelay);
`...if you have another error, add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need for any of this to be unsafe and use pointers. Making some basic assumptions on the parameter semantics, you might use this declaration:

```
[DllImport("mpusbapi.dll")]
private static extern uint _MPUSBWrite(
    IntPtr handle, 
    byte[] data, 
    uint dataLength, 
    out uint sentDataLength, 
    uint timeoutMS
);
```

I don't know what the calling convention should be. You use both `stdcall` and `cdecl` in the question. Rather than guessing, you need to find out definitively.

Comment: I made the changes and seem like it works, but then I have the exception  'PInvokeStackImbalance'.

Comment: Well, that's usually because the calling convention is wrong. Read my final paragraph. You have to determine the calling convention and specify it. I cannot do that from here.

Comment: Thanks, man. I added the Calling convention cdecl and the exception was solved. Now I'm testing the program, let see if it works